# Which motherboard manufacture(s) are the most Linux-friendly?

Tags: hardware

I am looking to upgrade my motherboard to support DDR3, USB 3.0, and socket AM3+ CPUs.  I have used Gigabyte and ASRock motherboards without any serious issues.  I have been a fan of AMD for years now and try to stick with them.  Which motherboard manufacture(s) are the most Linux-friendly?

Answer (score 3):

I think any manufacturer that supplies Linux drivers are OK.  Personally, I would use Intel or Gigabyte.  If you want complete hardware compatibility with Ubuntu, then you may want to check out the Ubuntu [Hardware Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport) page.

Comment: Seems these programs have been discontinued, except Ubuntu Certified which does not have any information on retail hardware but only complete systems.

Answer (score 3):

ALWAYS do your research on the particular motherboard first. Some people say to use Gigabyte but they had an issue a few years back

[Gigabyte, install windows to fix linux](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTAwMjg)

I personally had an issue installing ubuntu 12.04 server on a Gigabyte ga-990fxa-ud3 to which their tech support said to install windows to fix my ethernet problem.

Google the motherboard you want and see if there are any issues. Even if a particular brand is said to be linux friendly, it doesn't matter because you are only getting one motherboard and it needs to work.

Comment: This seems to be the best advice.  We unfortunately don't seem to have any 100% Linux-friendly mobo manufacturers...yet!

Comment: It seems that ASUS has pretty good support on most of their boards... http://www.asus.com/websites/global/aboutasus/OS/Linux.pdf

Answer (score 0):

That is a somwhat subjective question. I normally dont use Linux on my Desktop, but I don't imagine you having problems with any manufacturer, excluding for specific models. Seeing as Asus has a lot of Ubuntu-based netbooks, I'd say they are very Linux-friendly, but if you don't have any issues with both Gigabyte and ASRock, then they should also be ok. But the best way is to search beforehand and get some feedback before buying a new motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing research on Linux based motherboards. Mostly on sites where people share their stories and problems with linux. The ASUS Z87 plus board is linux friendly. Check out the review on Newegg site.

Comment: In recent years, Asus has taken the attitude that the machines and motherboards they sell are for Windows machines (especially laptops but desktop motherboard features, too). If you can get it to work then lucky you but if not, tough. I no longer deal with them, just based on that attitude.

Comment: @Mike: reference? :)

Comment: They don't actually tell you this until you get a hold of tech support. Go figure.